# Use of functional Haskell-like Accumulator in javascript functions

Tags: javascript, haskell, underscore.js, lodash, ramda.js

I'm currently looking into Haskell and i'm fascinated by some of its features, for example the end-recursive functions using an accumulator.

Questions:

1. Is there a construct in javascript similar to that? Or does it even
   make sense regarding efficiency since javascript is not as
   functional as Haskell?
2. Is there any library like ramda, lodash, ... that supports this way
   of programming
3. And if so, how would you write this for example in javascript:

   ```
    power_acc :: Double -> Int -> Double
    power_acc x y = power_acc_h x y 1

    power_acc_h :: Double -> Int -> Double -> Double
    power_acc_h x 0 acc = acc
    power_acc_h x y acc = power_acc_h x (y-1) (acc*x)
   ```

Comment: My 2 cents: as much as I love functional programming, I find the idiom accumulator+recursion to be a somewhat inelegant encoding of a stateful `for` loop. In an imperative language, I'd prefer a loop over that FP idiom. Of course, sometimes such loops are actually folds, as in the posted example, and in such cases I find the FP higher-order folds to be more elegant than `for`s or accumulators. Of course, all of this is just a matter of personal taste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a construct in javascript similar to that?

Yes, you can literally translate this to JS:

```
function power_acc(x, y) { // Double -> Int -> Double
    y = y>>>0; // cast to positive int (avoiding nontermination)
    return power_acc_h(x, y, 1);
}
function power_acc_h(x, y, acc) { // Double -> Int -> Double -> Double
    return y == 0
      ? acc
      : power_acc_h(x, y-1, acc*x);
}
```

> Or does it even make sense regarding efficiency since javascript is not as functional as Haskell?

With ES6, tail recursion is fully supported in JS, and you'll get the same efficiency as with a loop (and possibly even better than haskell, as you don't create lazy multiplications).

> Is there any library like ramda, lodash, ... that supports this way of programming

No library required. Although I'm sure there are libs that simplify type checking or offer nicer notation for pattern matching.

> How would you write this for example in javascript?

You'd use a `while` loop. All accumulation functions in haskell are written this way because they can be directly optimised into a loop, and that's the notation you should use for this construct in JS (as most programmers are familiar with it):

```
function power_acc(x, y) { // Double -> Int -> Double
    y = y>>>0; // cast to positive int (avoiding nontermination)
    var acc = 1;
    while (y != 0) {
        acc *= x;
        y -= 1;
    }
    return acc;
}
```

Mutating local variables is no harm, your function is still pure. If you're looking for an even shorter notation, use a `for` loop.

Comment: "With ES6, tail recursion is fully supported in JS"  ... However, it's really [not implemented yet](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#proper_tail_calls_(tail_call_optimisation)).

Comment: @ScottSauyet: True (unless for babel). Just another reason to use the idiomatic loop :-)

Answer (score 4):

This is a direct translation of the Haskell code in javascript :

```
function power_acc(x, y) {
    return aux(x,y,1);
    function aux(x, y, acc) {
        if (y == 0)
            return acc;
        else
            return aux(x, y-1, acc*x);
    }
}
```

> Is there any library like ramda, lodash, ... that supports this
>   way of programming?

You don't need lodash or ramda for that. You can do that with your
plain javascript just as I have shown above. Also note that lodash is
an utility library providing a consistent API for operating with
collections in a functional way. It won't help you in these scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Sibi's answer, I'd like to point out that javascript (at least nodejs) actually allocates stack space. It works fine and fast up to exponents of about 13,000, then you'll get `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`. To carry out this experimant you need to set the base to a number close to 1 (e.g. 1.0001) or you'll get Infinity.

Haskell does not suffer from this problem. An exponent 1000 times as big (namely 13,000,000) still does not cause any space problems, though it does take a few seconds to run. This is because the recursion is a tail call, and these run in constant space in haskell.

So in a way Sibi's answer mimicks haskells expressiveness, but it still exhibits a different runtime behavior. I don't think there is anythining you can do about this.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with all the answers in that a library is neither required nor particularly helpful.  (I'm one of the authors of Ramda, BTW.)

Bergi's translation into JS is fine, although I think it's more idiomatic at least in browser-side JS, to embed the helper function inside a local closure, something a little closer to Sibi's answer.

The reason for the performance problem that Martin Drautzburg points out is that, although tail-call optimization [is specified](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-preparefortailcall), it's [barely implemented](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#proper_tail_calls_(tail_call_optimisation)) anywhere.  One exception is Babel's support for direct recursion, so a Babel-transpiled version should get the expected performance benefit.

So if you want to do this because of the elegance and because you believe TCO will come along soon enough, and if you're not worried about current possible performance problems, then these responses are useful, and I'll even throw one more ES6 technique into the mix:

```
// Double -> Int -> Double -> Double
function powerAcc(x, y, acc = 1) {
    return y == 0 ? acc : powerAcc(x, y - 1, acc * x);
}

powerAcc(2, 5); //=> 32
```

[Default function parameters](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation) help replace some simple forms of pattern matching in this language, which doesn't have true pattern matching.  This still relies on TCO, but makes for somewhat cleaner code.  It should also run performantly in Babel.